# Is my plan for a new bathroom lighting and fan circuit code-compliant?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bathroom, dimmer-switch

[image]

I am adding a new lighting circuit to my bathroom remodel and wanted to get some feedback on my planned wiring layout. This circuit is in addition to a pre-existing dedicated 20A circuit for the outlets.

I am going to feed a 3 gang box with a 14/2 15A circuit from my breaker box. Then pigtail the hot and neutral to 1 dual dimmer switch, and a deadface GFCI.

From the dual dimmer, I was going to run 14/3 to a vanity fixture and 2 pot lights, sharing the neutral.

The second run will go to the GFCI, then to a dimmer and timer combo, then a 14/3 run to a pot light in the shower and an exhaust fan, also in the shower wet area. This run will also share the neutral.

My original plan was to run 14/2 from each switch to each fixture, but it would seem more efficient to pull 2 14/3 runs rather than 4 14/2 runs, especially due to challenges in the structure to get the wiring thru.

Thoughts on this layout being code compliant? Any opinions for improvement?

Comment: Is there a 20A SABC running to this bathroom already?

Comment: Is this a dual sink or only single?

Comment: Are you planning to stay with incandescent bulbs until the end of time?  If not, you may want to think about LED fixtures (no need to even bother with removable bulbs anymore) and dimmers which are properly matched to those LED fixtures.   Those dimmers will assuredly need a neutral wire.

Comment: This is going to be a single sink install. We are adding the pot lights to the general lighting area since the room is dark wroth only the vanity fixture. As for LEDS, yes we are planning to use dimmable LEDs in these fixtures. But in researching Harper's comment about needing neutrals, I have found my dimmers are not compatible with due to the low load of the Led bulbs.  Time for plan B.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a 20A small appliance branch circuit feeding receptacles in the bathroom in question, your plan is fine.  NEC 210.23(C)(3) requires that at least one of the bathroom receptacle outlets is on a 20A bathroom SABC, but still allows additional receptacles to be on a 15A circuit.

> **(3) Bathroom Branch Circuits.** In addition to the number
>   of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at
>   least one 120-volt, 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to supply a bathroom receptacle outlet(s). Such circuits shall have no other outlets.